# HTTP Статусы

Tags: http

Шарился по нету в поисках списка возможных статусов HTTP. Нашел интересную картинку, пригодится тем, кто задается вопросом "Почему сервер выдает ошибку и что делать".

Answer (score 4):

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Http-headers-status.gif

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Http-headers-status.gif]

Действительно жаль, что нет :( Можно было бы выкладывать туда какие-нибудь информационные вещи)

Comment: Ну это и не вопрос впринципе :) Кстати жалко что нету соответсвующего раздела для информативных топиков :(

@Alex Silaev, отличная картинка!

Comment: Картинка устарела, в ней лишь 27 кодов из 41-го https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.1